# Hi I'm trying to run my azure pipeline on self hosted agent but getting error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Below error I'm getting while checkout task
##[error]File not found: 'git'

Comment: You have to install git on your VM

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed Git on the agent machine.

You can download the latest version of Git [here](https://git-scm.com/), and then install it on the agent machine.

After completing the installation successfully, restart the machine or the agent service. Then you can use the **`git`** command on the machine or in the pipeline jobs which run on the agent.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamGurao, I have not heard from you for a long time. whether you have viewed my answer? Are the explanations in my answer helpful for you?
As explained in my answer, you need to download and install Git on the agent machine so that your pipeline tasks can run the git commands.